# Concatenating strings in JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove nested `<b></b>` tags. See the generated css and you'll understand the problem:

```
<div class="highlight" contenteditable="true">
    ahuasdhuasdhuasdhu 
    <b>
       <b>#</b>
       huadshuashud
    </b>
</div>
```

I want remove the  tags that have a '# inside, but I don't want remove the '#'. (Note the hashtag can be any another value). For this, I wrote the following code:

```
// Highlight already been declared and just is a simple $('.highlight').
highlight.children('b').children('b').contents().unwrap();
```

Now I have the following code:

```
<div class="highlight" contenteditable="true">
    ahuasdhuasdhuasdhu 
    <b>
        "#"
        "huadshuashud"
    </b>
</div>
```

I want join this two strings, because when I double click it, it just select "#" or "huadshuashud", but I want that all content inside the  tag is selected.

Have some way to improve my method or concatenate these two strings?

Comment: So I presume the `""` are literally in the HTML?

Comment: Yes, they're literally in the HTML :/

Comment: *"because when I double click it, it just select "#""* Ah, so the *actual* problem. The default behaviour, in chrome anyway, is to select in this way. Try it by selecting this text: "#abc123". You'd need to create *extra* JS that looks for those click selections and "fix" the browser-specific behaviour. Not fun.

Comment: Thanks @Hamish, this is exactly my problem and is what I reported in comment of "eclanrs" answer. Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: If you want post a answer to my question, I will give you best answer. You don't tell me how to do that, but you told me that is almost impossible :P

Comment: google is good at understanding text, maybe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.highlight > b').html(function(){
  return $(this).text();
});
```

Which will give you this:

```
<b>
  #
  huadshuashud
</b>
```

Comment: You're rigth eclanrs, your answer give me "<b>#heuehueheu</b>", but I don't know, when I double click it I just get "#" or "heuehueheu" selected. This's a browser issue?

Comment: That's just the way it is, try any other symbol, and dbl-click will just select the word characters, it's not an issue. Try dbl-click on this string "#asdasdasd".

Answer (score 1):

[Selecting text in an element (akin to highlighting with your mouse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse)

Here you have a ready function. Edit the beginning to be able to pass an object instead of id and add a handler:

```
$(".highlight").ondblclick(function(){
    SelectText(this)
})

function SelectText(elementObject) {
    // here choose function you like and replace text variable
    text = elementObject;
    ...
```